# Is there a way to chain generator expressions such that a downstream conditional prevents evaluation of unchecked upstream elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

As a general example I have 2 generator expressions like:

```
items = ((i,i**2) for i in range(0,100))
tens = ((i,j) for i,j in items if isaMultipleOf10(i))
```

The second expression is only checking the first element of the first expression, so technically the "i**2" expression in the second element should not need to be evaluated except for true results, however the second element is evaluated for each check regardless of a true/false.

I realize there are various convoluted ways to achieve this such as by making some wrapper for the second element to prevent it's evaluation, however I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this more simply without having to make any significant changes to the first expression.

Comment: You could skip the first expression entirely? `((i,i**2) for i in range(100) if isaMultipleOf10(i))`

Comment: By definition, you can't. The point of generator expressions is that they allow for lazy evaluation. If you do not want something to be evaluated, do not put it early in your generator expression chain.

As pointed by @Tomer , you could skip the first expression entirely to apply your filter.

Why do you need not to touch the first expression?